# How to show app intro only once (first run time) with AsyncStorage - React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, asyncstorage

I use this library for my app intro: https://github.com/Jacse/react-native-app-intro-slider

This is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import {Container} from 'native-base';
import AppIntroSlider from 'react-native-app-intro-slider';
import { AntDesign } from '../../styles/variables/Icons';

export default class TestView extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showRealApp: false,
      //To show the main page of the app
    };
  }
  _onDone = () => {
    // After user finished the intro slides. Show real app through
    // navigation or simply by controlling state
    this.setState({ showRealApp: true });
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Home');
  };
  _onSkip = () => {
    // After user skip the intro slides. Show real app through
    // navigation or simply by controlling state
    this.setState({ showRealApp: true });
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Home');
  };
```

```
    render() {
    //If false show the Intro Slides
    if (this.state.showRealApp) {
      //Real Application
      return (
        <View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            padding: 50,
          }}>
          <Text>
            This will be your screen when you click Skip from any slide or Done
            button at last
          </Text>
        </View>
      );
    } else {
      //Intro slides
      return (
        <Container>
          <AppIntroSlider
            slides={slides}
            //comming from the JsonArray below
            onDone={this._onDone}
            //Handler for the done On last slide
            showSkipButton={true}
            onSkip={this._onSkip}
            showPrevButton={true}
            prevLabel={<AntDesign name="arrowleft" size={23} />}
            nextLabel={<AntDesign name="arrowright" size={23}/>}
            doneLabel="Готово"
          />
        </Container>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

How I can show app intro only once (first run time) and save it to cache with AsyncStorage?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can accomplish this using the [AsyncStorage](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage) API
Here's a very quick approach to do it:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, AsyncStorage, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import {Container} from 'native-base';
import AppIntroSlider from 'react-native-app-intro-slider';
import { AntDesign } from '../../styles/variables/Icons';

export default class TestView extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showRealApp: false,
      loading: true,
      //To show the main page of the app
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('first_time').then((value) => {
      this.setState({ showRealApp: !!value, loading: false });
    });
  }

  _onDone = () => {
    // After user finished the intro slides. Show real app through
    // navigation or simply by controlling state
    AsyncStorage.setItem('first_time', 'true').then(() => {
      this.setState({ showRealApp: true });
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Home');
    });
  };

  _onSkip = () => {
    // After user skip the intro slides. Show real app through
    // navigation or simply by controlling state
    AsyncStorage.setItem('first_time', 'true').then(() => {
      this.setState({ showRealApp: true });
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Home');
    });
  };

  render() {
    if (this.state.loading) return <ActivityIndicator size="large" />

    //If false show the Intro Slides
    if (this.state.showRealApp) {
      //Real Application
      return (
        <View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            padding: 50,
          }}>
          <Text>
            This will be your screen when you click Skip from any slide or Done
            button at last
          </Text>
        </View>
      );
    } else {
      //Intro slides
      return (
        <Container>
          <AppIntroSlider
            slides={slides}
            //comming from the JsonArray below
            onDone={this._onDone}
            //Handler for the done On last slide
            showSkipButton={true}
            onSkip={this._onSkip}
            showPrevButton={true}
            prevLabel={<AntDesign name="arrowleft" size={23} />}
            nextLabel={<AntDesign name="arrowright" size={23}/>}
            doneLabel="Готово"
          />
        </Container>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: is AsyncStorage is safe to use in production ??

Comment: @MahiGunjal depends on how you use it, but I wouldn't recommend storing any secret values in it.